# Sharepoint 2010 MySites configuration

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint

I have two Sharepoint applications: a user portal and a MySites applications.  Both are configured for local publishing through an internal FQDN and externally via SSL through Forefront TMG.  I have configured the alternate access mappings for the external FQDN using the "Internet".

When I access the portal application locally and then select the MySites links, both applications work as expected, but when I access the site externally, the MySites application breaks because it is trying to connect to the internal FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up an alternate access mapping for the My Sites web application too? You should configure your internet zone URL's for both web applications to the correct URL's in order for this to work.